# Как проверить, содержит ли переменная часть текста. php

Tags: php

Как можно проверить, содержит ли переменная конкретный фрагмент текста. Именно не весь текст, а например первое слово?

То есть у меня есть переменная `$pagetitle`, которая содержит некий текст. Мне нужно проверить, содержит ли она слово "телевизор", и если содержит, то выполняются какие-то действия.

Comment: http://php.net хоть раз открывали? Там много интересного

Comment: Подскажите, пжлст, а как в моем случае применить то, что вы сейчас посоветовали? Например есть 4 типа значений: Мужской, Женский, Красивые дети, Какой-то другой текст.
Есть такая функция: function my_map_data( $data ) { $map = array( 'Мужской' => 'Для мужчин', 'Женский' => 'Для женщин', ); return ( array_key_exists( $data, $map ) ) ? $map[ $data ] : $data; } В данном случае функция переводит только то, что указано дословно. А мне нужно так: Если "Женский", то записать "Для женщин". Если "Мужской", то записать "Для мужчин". Если содержится слово "дети", то записать "Для детей". Если любой друго

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Всё намного проще, есть функция:

```
strpos($text, 'телевизор');
```

Если слово `"телевизор"` есть в строке, то функция вернет позицию, с которой начинается слово, или `false`, если слово не нашлось.

Answer (score 15):

**Вариант 1:**

Стоит почитать про регулярные выражения. Там всё просто, если почитать)

```
$text = "В этом тексте есть нужное слово";
```

Ищем "слово"

```
preg_match("/слово/", $text, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

**Вариант 2:**

Можно воспользоваться функцией [strpos](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php)

```
if (strpos($text, 'слово') !== false) // именно через жесткое сравнение
{
    echo 'Найдено';
} else {
    echo 'Не найдено';
}
```

Comment: Регулярные выражения работают значительно медленнее, чем простые функции типа strpos.

Comment: @SergeyRusakov, я не спорю. Хотя Вы правы, более полный ответ должен был бы содержать несколько вариантов ответа