# Как проверить содержит ли строка элементы массива?

Tags: php, строки

Нашел вот такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/257866/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-php), но тут приводится пример с одним словом.
Как проверить на содержание в строке группы слов ?

> Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку

Как например проверить, что в предложении выше есть слова "сушку, Саша, шла" и, если хотя бы одно из слов найдено, вывести сообщение, что совпадение найдено.

При этом, если найдено 10 совпадений, то сообщение должно быть одно, а не 10.

Сейчас написано так: `if(!strpos($link, 'Слово')){...` Ну вот на месте "слово" я хочу перечислить несколько и по ним проверять, а не писать бесконечное `or`.

В голове сейчас крутится только то, что можно несколько раз условиями перебрать.

Comment: `strpos()` возвращает позицию вхождения, которая может равняться нулю, поэтому проверку стоит делать с использованием оператора `===` и сравнивать с `false`, который возвращается, если искомая строка не найдена

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я использовал array_intersect, он возвращает, слова которые повторяются в первом массиве.

```
$str = explode(' ','Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку');
$str2 = explode(' ', 'сушку Саша Шла');
$res = array_intersect($str, $str2);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: а если у меня большой текст, и в зависимости от того, есть совпадения или нет, выполнить функцию? При том, если  найдены совпадения, функция должна выполниться однократно, а не каждый раз, когда сравнили с элементом массива и ничего не нашли. Вот это не понял как сделать

Comment: что должно возврoшаться если слова нашлись?

Comment: ну в моем случае если не нашлись просто функция выполниться должна. Пусть возвращается просто echo 'выполнена функция',

Comment: сейчас написано так: if(!strpos($link, 'Слово')){... ну вот на месте "слово" я хочу перечислить несколько и по ним проверять.

Answer (score 2):

Решил сделать вот так, и вроде как нагрузку не дает

```
$text = "Танцуй пока молодой и ещё несколько слов";
$slova = array('Танцуй', 'пока', 'молодой');
$m = false; //ставлю флаг
foreach($slova as $slovo) {
  if (strpos($text, $slovo) !== false) {
    $m = true; // если слова найдены то переключаю на ИСТИНА
  }
}
if ($m) { //если истина то выполняю условие
  echo 'в тексте есть совпадения';
}
//после выполнения снова можно переключить флаг
```

скажите насколько это рабочая тема, можно ли упростить?

Comment: не плохо! все будет работать

Answer (score 1):

[отсюда](http://www.cyberforum.ru/php-beginners/thread1217594.html)

```
$text = "Танцуй пока молодой и ещё несколько слов";
$slova = array('Танцуй', 'пока', 'молодой');
foreach($slova as $item)
     {
      if (preg_match("/$item/",$text)) echo "В предложении есть слово - ".$item."<br>";
     }
```

Comment: но при этом если написать else "не найдено", то каждый раз при обходе будет выводить "не найдено", а можно как-то сделать, чтобы foreach перебрал $text по всем элементам $slova и если хотя бы один элемент найден, то просто в конце вывелось, что есть совпадения? просто если нет совпадений мне нужно выполнить функцию однократно, а если есть то не выполнять

Comment: Но зачем регулярка? Ладно бы сделать это без цикла используя альтернативы: `/(Танцуй|пока|молодой)/ui`, но в вашем варианте и `strpos/stripos` подойдет

Answer (score 1):

```
function isThereWordsLikeThis($text, $allWords)
{
   foreach ($allWords as $word)
      if (stripos($text, $word) !== false) return true;
   return false;
}

   $allWords = ['Сушку', 'Саша', 'Шла'];
   $text = 'Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку'; 
if(isThereWordsLikeThis($text, $allWords)) echo 'в тексте есть по крайней мере одно совпадение!';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stop = 0;
$text = "Танцуй пока молодой и ещё несколько слов";
$stop_arr = array('Танцуй', 'пока', 'молодой');
foreach($stop_arr as $item)
     {
      if (preg_match("/$item/",$text)) $stop = 1;
     }

if ($stop == 0) 
    {
    //вхождений не найдено
    }
else 
    {
    //есть вхождение
    }
```